# Warning when compiling and executing application on Uno Platform with the Skia.Gtk project

Tags: .net, ubuntu, uno-platform

I am training myself on Uno development on an Ubuntu 20.04. I created a uno application with `dotnet new unoapp -o Tutorial2`  After `dotnet run` the Uno application on Gtk starts. Anyway I am facing a warning (twice):

> .../Tutorial2.Skia.Gtk/Tutorial2.Skia.Gtk.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'SkiaSharp.Views 2.80.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8'
> instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'.
>  This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

This warning is not a big issue for now but I suspect it to lead for further problems later and I suspect it also to be linked with errors I get with the other ports of Uno. Therefore I should be very pleased to understand what is happening.
I checked the Tutorial2.Skia.Gtk.csproj but I did not find any reference regarding the .Net sdk to use. The installed sdks on my machine are 3.1.405 and 5.0.102
Any idea ?